# How do I use string formatting for bash commands in python without calling NoneType?

Tags: python, bash, types, terminal, formatting

I created a sliding window program a while back and I am trying to use bash commands with it.

I need to use several programs later on with bash commands, so using bash is a necessity.

I created a master_function that joins pair commands.

So the command is entered in bash like so:

```
python swindow.py sliding_window window,interval,second_window path/window{0},5,path/window{1}
```

and Python should interpret it like this:

```
python swindow.py sliding_window -window path/window{0} -interval 5 -path/window{1}
```

I want {0} and {1} to be used as int for the window number {i.e. window0, window 1, etc.) so I used .format(x,x) to specify the window numbers.

Here is the functional that changes {0} and {1} to ints.
When I try to use this function, it returns the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

How do I fix this problem? I've tried using {{0}}, using %i instead of .format, and several other techniques but none work.

```
def master_function():
    program = sys.argv[1]
    arguments_list = sys.argv[2].split(",")
    arguments_values_list = sys.argv[3].split(",")
    argument_value_pairs_list = zip(arguments_list, arguments_values_list)

    com = program + "".join(" -" + arg_pair[0] + " -" + arg_pair[1] for arg_pair in argument_value_pairs_list) 
    x = 0

    return com.format(0,0)
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of your exception? The code you showed is almost certainly not the cause.

Comment: I think you should use argv[0] for program name and argv[1], argv[2] for parameters.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' is only the error that comes back if try 'return com.format(0,0)'

Comment: When I call your `master_function()` in a program with arguments as you described, I get `sliding_window -window -path/window0 -interval -5 -second_window -path/window0` in return, no error.